# Rerun Airflow Dag From Middle Task and continue to run it till end of all downstream tasks.(Resume Airflow DAG from any task)

Tags: airflow

Hi i am new to Apache Airflow i have dag of dependancies lets say

Task A >> Task B >> Task C >> Task D >> Task E

1. Is it possible to run Airflow DAG from middle task lets say Task C ?
2. Is it possible to run only specific branch in case of branching
   operator in middle?
3. Is it possible to resume Airflow DAG from last failure task?
4. If not possible how to manage large DAG's and avoid rerunning
   redundant tasks?

Please provide me suggestions on how to implement this if possible.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can't do it manually. If you set BranchPythonOperator you can skip tasks till the task you wish to start with according to the conditions set in the BranchPythonOperator
2. Same as 1.
3. yes. You can clear tasks upstream till root or down stream till all leaves of the node.

You can do something like:

```
Task A >> Task B >> Task C >> Task D
Task C >> Task E
```

Where `C` is the branch operator.
For example:

```
    from datetime import date
    def branch_func():
        if date.today().weekday() == 0:
            return 'task id of D'
        else:
            return 'task id of E'


    Task_C = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='branch_operation',
        python_callable=branch_func,
        dag=dag)
```

This will be task sequence on Monday :

```
Task A >> Task B >> Task C >> Task D
```

This will be task sequence on rest of the week:

```
Task A >> Task B >> Task C >> Task E
```

Comment: Yes branching operator is there but my question is around starting dag from middle . In branching case also is it possible to start it from branch i.e Task C

Comment: You can start the DAG from more than 1 point but you must set conditions to skip the branch you wish to not run.

Comment: Yes i tried with branch and having skip task but when i trigger only branch task then it is not continuing from branch till end. In above example as you mentioned if i hit command e.g " airflow run dag_id task_c date " then in my UI i am able to see task_c executing task_d but if i have some more task after  task_d 
lets say task_f its not working. Do you have some examples or blogs could you please share it.

Comment: Why not separating for more than one DAG?

Comment: Yes thats one of the option we have. So i think directly doing it without any branching and all is not possible.